# Is this induction proof mathematically correct?

Tags: induction

Proof that $\frac{n^3}{3} < 3n-3$ is true for $n=2$ but false for every other $ n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Idea is to proof that $\frac{n^3}{3} \geq 3n-3$.

Let  $n$ be $n=3$

$\frac{27}{3}  \geq 9-3 $.
That means $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{n^3}{3} \geq 3n-3$ and therefore the same for $n = n+1$.

We have to proof that $\frac{n^3}{3} >= 3n-3$ for $n=n+1$ which means $\frac{(n+1)^3}{3} \geq 3(n+1)-3 = \frac{(n+1)^3}{3} \geq 3n$

We have  $\frac{(n+1)^3}{3} = \frac{n^3+3n^2+3n+1}{3} = \frac{n^3}{3} + \frac{3n^2+3n+1}{3}$

Now we use that $\frac{n^3}{3} \geq 3n-3$.

$\frac{3n-3}{3} + \frac{3n^2+3n+1}{3} = \frac{3n^2+6n-2}{3} = n^2+2n-\frac23$

Can I now just say that $\forall n > 3; n \in \mathbb{N}$
$n^2+2n-\frac23 > 3n$
is true und therefore our statement $\frac{n^3}{3} < 3n-3$ is proven?

Thanks to everyone who takes some time to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont write $n=n+1$ you can write $n\mapsto n+1$.

The typical way to estimate from $n^2+2n-\frac23$ is to use, that $n\geq 3$.
This helps dealing with the quadratic term. The rest is simple.

Comment: So $n*n+2n+1 \geq 3n + 2n - \frac23 \geq 3n + 6 - \frac23 \geq 3n$ should be okay?

Comment: @DidseaJ Exactly.